# Best design pattern for 2 classes with similar behavior

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 2 class:

class A, which contains a lot of functions.

```
Class A{
  public void a(int param1, int param2);
  public void b(String param1, int param2);
....}
```

Class B has also the same functions, but some of the params are redundant,

```
Class B{
  public void a(int param1forB){}
  public void b(String param1){}
....}
```

I have tests which check class A. I want to use these tests also for class B.

Another two issues:

1. `B` contains functions that implement in some classes of `A`. for example,  `a` is in class `A1`, and function `b` is in class `A2`
2. I want to minimize the changes in A (when in B, I can change anything I want).

Any idea?

Comment: You could have class B extend class A

Comment: @kustrle: But I need multiple extension, and Java doesn't support it (Because issue number 1).

Comment: class A1 implements ifcA1{}; class A2 implements ifcA2 {}; class B implements ifcA1, ifcA2 {}

Answer (score 0):

Let B extends A , then override the methods  you wish to have different behavior in B. keep the method in A public if you wish to change the signature  of methods in B by using overload. and be sure to remove the @override annotation automatically added by the IDE when making overload.
and for multiple inheritance you are right java do not support that from multi class so you must choose interface to do multi inheritance

Comment: But I need multiple extension, and Java doesn't support it (Because issue number 1).

Comment: regarding issue one what do you mean B implements classes of A , class will never implement class it can implements interface and extends class.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template as per [Template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

```
public abstract class templateClass
{
    public abstract void a();
    public abstract void b();
}


public class A extends templateClass
{
    public void a() {

    }

    public void b() {
    }
}

public class B extends A
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Interface` and `Composition Over Inheritance` can help you solve the issue. Examples (maybe exists some syntax error, it's already long time since I used java):

```
public interface IFunctionA{
    void a(int param1, int param2);
    void a(int param1);
}

public interface IFunctionB{
    void b(String param1, int param2);
    void b(String param1);
}

public class FunctionA implement IFunctionA{
    public void a(int param1, int param2){
        //do the function
    }
}

// same with FunctionB

public class A{
    private IFunctionA functionA = new FunctionA();
    // same with b

    public void a(int param1, int param2){
        functionA.a(param1, param2);
    }

    //same with function b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If methods a from class A and B are similar in behavior, you can replace the parameters by a parameters class. This will define two get methods (param1 and param2) you need two constructors, one with both parameters to be used by class A and with only one argument for class B (there are actually several solutions to get the same result).

In this way both classes can implement the same interface:

```
public interface ABInterface {
    void a(AParams params);
    void b(BParams params);
    ...
}

public class AParams implements ABInterface {

    private int param1;
    private int param2;

    public AParams(int param1, int param2) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public AParams(int param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;        
    }

    public int getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }


    public int getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }      
}

public class BParams implements ABInterface {

    private String param1;
    private int param2;

    public BParams(String param1, int param2) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public BParams(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;        
    }

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }


    public int getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }      
}


public class A{
    public void a(AParams params) {
        ...
    }
    public void b(BParams params) {
        ...
    }
    ...
  }

public class B{
    public void a(AParams params){
       ... 
    }
    public void b(BParams params){
       ...
    }
    ...
}



public void someMethod() {
    // you can new invoke these methods like this
    a.a(new AParams(1,2));
    b.a(new AParams(1));
    // but also like this, to reuse existing code
    AParams params = new AParams(1,2);
    a.a(params);
    b.a(params);    
}
```